Interrupting a form
I have a form and I want to be able to leave it if the user expresses this intent. However, in my case, rasa detects the intent "stop", but states there's no rule for this scenario, even though it's specified.
My form (domain.yml)
entities:
  - material

slots:
  material:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    mappings:
      - type: from_text
        conditions:
         - active_loop: catering_order
           requested_slot: material

forms:
  create_order:
    required_slots:
        - material

And my rule (rules.yml)
- rule: Interrupt form
  condition:
  # Condition that form is active.
  - active_loop: create_order
  steps:
  - intent: stop
  - action: action_deactivate_loop
  - active_loop: null
  - slot_was_set:
    - requested_slot: null
  - action: utter_goodbye


The bot goes to the "submit form" scenario, not "interrupt form" scenario
I tried to create rule without the condition
  - active_loop: create_order

and chang influence_conversation to True, both these options didn't help.
